# Collect AND do something under a condition inside a Common Lisp loop

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I need to execute an instruction in addition of "collect" under a condition in a loop and I can't figure out a working syntax...

For instance I'd like the following code to print i and collect it whenever 2 < i.

```
(loop for i '(1 2 3 4) in  when (< 2 i) (print i) collect i)  ==> (3 4)
```

Hoping you can help !

Comment: 2 cents: you might like [shinmera's For](https://github.com/Shinmera/for), which is simple and consistent.

Comment: By all means follow @Sylvester's link to Seibels chapter on LOOP; the funky syntax is not something one can guess at or even remember after much use (and I love LOOP).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple clauses in `:if` or `:when` needs to be joined by `:and`. The keyword `:end` actually is ignored and does nothing else than make you feel more at ease reading it.

```
(loop :for i :in '(1 2 3 4)
      :when (< 2 i) 
        :do (print i) 
        :and :collect i
      :end)  ; ==> (3 4) (and prints 3 and 4 as side effect)
```

I suggest you read [LOOP for Black Belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html). If you look [right above this part](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html#setting-up-and-tearing-down) you'll see `:and` in a slightly more complex example.

NB: `loop` accepts symbols from any package so my style is to use the keyword package not to pollute my own package with `loop` keywords and my editor highlights it slightly better. You don't need to do it my way :-)

Comment: The keyword END is part of the LOOP syntax, though.

Comment: The loop keywords are recognized by name. Thus even a symbol not interned in a package works.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yes, or else `:end` wouldn't be allowed where I put it. Perhaps one of the bad things with using the symbol package is that a typo like `:endd` would be evaluated if the two clauses were in oposite order.

Comment: No, :ENDD is not a known loop keyword. It would cause an error. Symbols/numbers/... are not allowed there, only compound forms. If there is a symbol, it must be a loop keyword.

Comment: @RainerJoswig If you switch the order so that it is `(loop :for i :in '(1 2 3 4) :when (< 2 i) :collect i :and :do (print i) :endd)` it will look like a second expression of the `:do` keyword and pass. If it weren't from the symbol package it most likely would have been an unbound variable error.

Comment: No, actually it won't work. :ENDD is neither a compound form nor a LOOP keyword. Check the syntax of LOOP. After the DO keyword there must be compound forms, not expressions (nor actually forms, a form is an object which can be evaluated). Thus you'll get an error:  Unknown LOOP keyword in (... :ENDD).

Comment: @RainerJoswig because of the implicit `progn` of `do` (you can have many expressions) the code in my previous comment works. Try it out.

Comment: Lispworks: Unknown LOOP keyword in (... :ENDD) . CCL: :ENDD is an unknown keyword in LOOP macro. SBCL: unknown LOOP keyword: :ENDD

Comment: ` (you can have many expressions) ` -> no you can't. The LOOP syntax permits many **compound forms**. A compound form is a list. A macro call, a function call, a lambda form or a special form. Anything else is not allowed. That's one of the the pitfalls for LOOP. ;-)

Comment: @RainerJoswig Works in CLISP.  It seems all the others actually doesn't recognize variables. eg. `(defparameter *t* 1) (loop :for n :to 2 :do (print n) *t*)` gives "unknown LOOP keyword: *T*" while if i replace it with `(print *t*)` it works.

Comment: check the syntax of LOOP in the ANSI CL standard. Not allowed: symbols, numbers, strings, arrays, clos objects, ... Allowed: compound forms. You might want to file a bug report to the CLISP maintainers because of not conforming to ANSI Common Lisp. At least it should warn about non-portable code.

Comment: See under **unconditional**. We get this: **{do | doing} compound-form+** . The glossary then says: **compound form n. a non-empty list which is a form: a special form, a lambda form, a macro form, or a function form.** That's a tricky part of the LOOP syntax.

Comment: @RainerJoswig It makes sense since `:do` is only for side effects and evaluating a variable has not side effects. I've submitted a bug report. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
CL-USER 71 > (loop for i in '(1 2 3 4)
                   when (> i 2)
                     do (print i) and collect i)

3        ; printed
4        ; printed
(3 4)    ; return value
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it would be shorter to use the return value of print:

```
(loop for i in '(1 2 3 4) when (> i 2) collect (print i))
```

Comment: That was not what I really needed to do, it was just a simpler example. There's no `print` in the actual code !